# os.path.exists get stuck and never return a result

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.path

Is there a limit to the number of files `os.path.exists()` can check ?

I have a folder with a very high number of files (the folder size is about 44Gb. however I cannot get the number of files through `ls` or any other way I tried).

When I use the `os.path.exists()` function on that folder, the function never returns (I let it run for more than 1 hour).

The number of files to check is very high, I agree, but if the function returns something with N-1 files after a few seconds, it's supposed to also return something with N files, and not getting stuck somewhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

EDIT to add some code:

```
folder = '/var/local/myfolder'
filename = '20190418_fileblabla.xml'
filepath = os.path.join(folder, filename)

if os.path.exists(filepath):
    return 1
else:
    return 2
```

It never returns 1 or 2

Comment: We cannot say anything productive unless we see the code :)

Comment: If you do `os.path.exists(folder)`, then it should instantly return a value.

Comment: is you disk accessible?Check if it is disk issue. your kernal can access the file (permission)?

Comment: or possibly a network share and a bad connection?

Comment: It's on a server on which I am currently connected with sudo rights

I added a piece of code in the question

Comment: If `ls` is struggling to give you a directory listing, then you have an issue with the file system itself. Using Python will not circumvent that. Having _many_ files in a directory can significantly degrade the performance of the file system because directory entry lookups slow down.